# "multiplying" two list of strings

Tags: python, list, concatenation

using Python3.5
i have two lists of strings, and i want to 'multiply' the two lists so i can do an ebay search for carparts, and print to the console.

```
cars = ['ford focus', 'honda civic', 'chevy truck',]
parts = ['ignition', 'head light']

for car in cars:
    for part in parts:
        print(cars[car]) + parts[part])
```

expected output:

```
>>>ford focus ignition
ford focus head light
honda civic ignition
honda civic head light
chevy truck ignition
chevy truck head light
```

Ive tried several different methods, but cant seem to get anything to give me the output i need. i attempted to use numpy, but couldnt figure out how to get it to install. "pip install numpy" at cmd kept giving me some sort of error that i couldnt figure out. i need the output to be both strings on the same line, because i will copy and paste them into a notepad document and utilize the data by the line for an ebay search.

Comment: i think i would need to know the question and the answer before i can tell you how my question is different.

Comment: Use `itertools.product`. And then you can do something as simple as `[' '.join(l) for l in itertools.product(cars, parts)]` to get your result

Comment: thanks @thefourtheye, but your page shows me how to enumerate my list. i dont need to enumerate the list, what i need is to print a list of car parts for every car. this is simply handling strings. im apologize if i didnt make it clear the first time.

Comment: @indianhearts Actually `car` and `part` variables itself will have the actual value, you don't have to index the `cars` and `parts` with them respectively. Simply do `print(car, part)`

Comment: oh gosh! that was easy as py. i guess i was thinking much too deeply about it, the correct answer was to do like you said:
    print(car + ' ' + part)

tremendous thanks.